# Beautify Table layout in plain text email

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have the following routine for converting a DataBable to plain text for presenting in an email. However, as you see from the included layout image, the header rows are out of alignment with the column data. Is there any way of getting it to align correctly?

[image]

```
Function MakeHtmlEmailFromDataTable(dt As DataTable) As System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim retVal As String = ""
    Dim html As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For Each col As System.Data.DataColumn In dt.Columns
        html.Append(col.Caption & vbTab & vbTab)
    Next

    For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In dt.Rows

        For i = 0 To dr.ItemArray.Length - 1
            html.Append(dr.ItemArray(i).ToString & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
        Next
        html.Append(vbTab & vbCrLf)
    Next

    Return html
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe try using another font - courier new.  I forget, but FixedLen or non-truetype - something

Comment: @AnthonyHome lol how many threads u answering today buddy ur fingers must be near bleding lol its going out to a webserice for the email to avoid authentication issues so dont think i can control the font

Comment: Yeah - waiting for DNN to finish downloading need to test an upgrade from v5 to V7.  Exciting...

Comment: @AnthonyHorne havent used dnn in ages what I am asking is can you get the column sizes out of dt info so can make it format better cause if  i just go tabs it wont flow right

Comment: Have you looked at using SSRS (the free version).  You can do some very nice things, including sending some very nice reports in PDF, excel, plain, etc.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne cant do that budy as is for custom in house pos software have to use their methods thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you can use html (tables).  Even the simplest of services can at least cater for HTML BODY (it is one the System.Net.Mail properties).

Comment: @AnthonyHorne in house developer dont have it switched on cause we usually deliverying content to tills that run xp

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Using DNN 7 already. It's a nice step up, imo

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn My wife does template design and implementations on that, so I only help. (and do technical and do module design...)

Comment: @DavidB Ahh.  You are having some real challenges there.  Hope our answers help.  My answer below requires some work (few lines of code), but will probably work.

Comment: @DavidB You can also play around with a stuff function (like SQL) to "replace" the content at a position of "spaces".  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968273/stuff-function-implementation-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is that you have two tabs between column in the header, and four tabs between columns in the data.

But going deeper, plain text will not automatically respect tab stops to make columns. The only way you can fix this is if you have some idea of how long your data will be, relative to how long a tab stop is. This means you have a big problem, because tab stops can be set differently on different systems and even in different applications within the same system. Even if you have a perfect understanding of your data widths, situations with weird tab stop sizes will throw you off. The only way the tab stop mechanism has any chance is with fixed-width fonts and if your data is all exactly the same length, or if you can guarantee what e-mail client will be used on what operating system.

Your only real chance is to use a system that actually allows you to define columns, such as with the  html suggested by the names in your code:

```
Function MakeHtmlEmailFromDataTable(dt As DataTable) As System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim html As New System.Text.StringBuilder("<table><thead><tr>")

    For Each col As System.Data.DataColumn In dt.Columns
        html.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}", "<th>", col.Caption, "</th>")
    Next

    html.AppendLine("</tr></thead><tbody>")

    For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
        html.Append("<tr>")
        For i = 0 To dr.ItemArray.Length - 1
            html.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}", "<td>", dr.ItemArray(i).ToString(), "</td>")
        Next
        html.AppendLine("</tr>")
    Next
    html.AppendLine("</tbody></table>")

    Return html
End Function
```

Comment: Coehoom yes cause i dont no how to set the width if i dont have those tabs they be all bunched up together that is the question I am asking how to lay it out better acording to column size and row width values

Comment: and it can only be plain text as is posted up to an email webservice

Comment: Added some new information to my answer that you should read. Also: any e-mail service worth using supports html messages.

Comment: Coehoom I tried that butthe developer doesnt have an html flag on email cause we deliver to xp clients running on tills

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too much data, you can loop twice.  Once to get max col sizes (into an array) and the next to populate html.  Then for the headers you basically do a mid (making the headers exactly the same size).  Then both the Header and the columns each only have a single  between them.