# replace char with star on certain position inside string

Tags: c#, .net

If I have string with some number like

```
var nr = "00011122233345721";
```

how can I replace eighth and last element inside string with `*` so the string become `0001112*23334572*`

Comment: use simply `[]` operator. string is an array of `char`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Tigran: That won't work. the indexer for `string` is read only

Comment: quick and simple approach would be to `first check the length of the string if it's >= 8 then use the substring function along with the string.Replace function`

Comment: You could also use a Regex: string s = Regex.Replace(nr,@"(.{7}).(.*?).$","$1*$2*")

Answer (score 2):

As string is immutable in c#, try as following:

```
char[] array = nr.ToCharArray();
array[7] = "*";
array[array.Length-1] = "*"
nr = new string(array);
```

Comment: This is a solid approach, though of course in production code you'd want to check the string is long enough (and use `.Length` not `.length`)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
      var nr1 = "00011122233345721";
        var array = nr1.ToCharArray();
        array[7] = '*';
        array[nr1.Length-1] = '*';
        nr1 = new string(array);
```

OR

```
        var nr = "00011122233345721";
        nr = nr.Insert(nr.Length - 1, "*");
        nr = nr.Remove(nr.Length-1);
        nr = nr.Insert(7, "*");
        nr = nr.Remove(8,1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is duplicate: [stuff function implementation in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968273/stuff-function-implementation-in-c-sharp)

In short, you cannot alter the contents of a string in .NET because it is an immutable object. You need to create a new string.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer